# Muslim proof of God in the form of written words and the Muslim name of God

Tags: quran

I am trying to understand Muslim belief about words of the Koran written as calligraphy.  Could you tell me if the following statement is correct?

Many Muslims claim that the proof of God’s existence is literally provided in the physical form of the words of the Koran when they are properly written using calligraphy.  In other words, their reasoning is: 1. The forms of the written words of the Koran are actually proof of the existence of God.  2. Since the physical words prove the existence of God, God must exist.

I am also trying to clarify the Muslim belief about the name of The Creator.  Could you tell me if the following statement is correct?

There is no universal agreement among Muslims about the name of God and Muslims believe that God has the 99 names used in the Quran, known as ‘the 99 Names of God’.  However, the most commonly used name is probably ‘Allah’, which is Arabic for ‘the God’.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: There's an agreement about the name of God, which is simply the God, or Allah in Arabic. These 99 names of God is how he refers to himself throughout the Qur'an. They're more like his properties.

Comment: The 99 names of Allah is a hadith reference the qur'an nowhere quotes an amount. Secondly I've never heard Muslims claim that the physical form of the words of the qur'an are a proof for Allah. And further at the time of the revelation of the qur'an the Arabic scripture was at a very basic level, calligraphy as we know by now and even distinctions between some letters didn't exist at the time. But I guess you mean something else.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your first question
It's written in the Qur'an itself that it is the Word of God. Calligraphy need not contribute to this. It is only a personal manifestation of devotion of the scribe to write it beautifully. It is a consequence and a manifestation of the faith of the scribe.

The Qur'an also speaks of the impossibility to bring forth the words of the Qur'an as a proof of its Origin.

The most original form of the Qur'an is however to be recited, which results from the fact that in the time of its revelation, most people were not able to read and write.